# Android Vulkan, checking support anisotropics

Tags: android, graphics, vulkan

How to check that device support anisotropics for Vulkan Graphics APi. For example for checking it on OPENGL used

```
String extension = GLES10.glGetString(GLES10.GL_EXTENSIONS);
```

and then check contains string "**GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic**".
How do it if used Vulkan Graphics api?

Comment: Why do you think the anisotropic texture filter means support for "antialiasing"? Usually, with AA we mean something completely different, to avoid aliasing artefacts of the _rasterization_, while the texure filters address aliasing artifacts in the texture mapping only.

Comment: Thanks for comment. Sorry, I was mistake, I mean anisotropics. Fixed my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anisotropic filtering is an optional device feature. You can query it with

```
VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures supportedFeatures;
vkGetPhysicalDeviceFeatures(device, &supportedFeatures);
```

`supportedFeatures.samplerAnisotropy` will contain a boolean stating if the feature is available.

If you actually wanted to check for MSAA, then you can check `supportedFeatures.limits.framebufferColorSampleCount` and `supportedFeatures.limits.framebufferDepthSampleCounts`

Comment: Is it means Anisotropics is equals Antialiasing for Vulcan?

Comment: No, not at all. But having the `GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic` also doesn't necessarily mean that the device supports antialiasing. The code checks for the exact same condition you were checking before.

Comment: Good, thanks :) Is Exists way to check that anisotropics support(more exactly) on device with Vulkan and for device with OpenGL? –